# c stdio File in visual studio 2010

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, file, stdio

i am learning c, and i am trying to follow many of examples i could find on web

as i encounter problem accessing some of the `stdio` keywords and `typedef`s
or types.

for instance

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 File *f; ---->error : identifier "f" is undefined
 //or found via codeblocs intellisense i also tried filebuf

 filebuf *f; ---->error : identifier "filebuf" is undefined
 // though this would compile 
 getc('');
}
```

as it's not able to loacte `File` struct

Comment: Your call to [`getc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) will lead to *undefined behavior*, and a probable crash.

Comment: C is case-sensitive, simple as that. Voting to close this as simple typo.

Comment: @SouravGhosh the lack of intellisense for inexperienced programer in c ... thanks

Comment: so should it be closed should i delete ?

Answer (score 1):

File should be changed to `FILE`.also `getc` function takes FILE pointer not `''`,and filebuf should be changed to `_iobuf`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *f;

    //_iobuf *f; 

    f = fopen("somefile","r");

    getc(f);
}
```

Comment: any suggestions for intellisense in vs ? (for c)